# Is there any way how we can implement WS-security token in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How to implement WS-Security with UsernameToken without liquid template

Answer (score 0):

there is no way right now in Azure APIM to use policy for this.you have to mention it in set-body policy